# CSV grouping and filtering out rows using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working on a scenario where my csv input file is as following:

| Name | Number | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123 | Second |
| Rocky | 345 | Third |
| Tony | 234 | First |
| Rocky | 345 | Second |
| Matt | 999 | Second |
| Bernard | 888 | Third |
| Matt | 999 | First |
| Jacob | 789 | Second |
| Angela | 777 | Second |
| Jacob | 789 | First |

Here through PowerShell, I am trying to get unique rows for Name, having a condition on priority column as it has values as First or Second then First should appear and vice versa if it has Second or Third then Second should appear.

Something like following

| Name | Number | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123 | Second |
| Rocky | 345 | Second |
| Tony | 234 | First |
| Matt | 999 | First |
| Bernard | 888 | Third |
| Jacob | 789 | First |
| Angela | 777 | Second |

I am not able to get it done, could any one throw any lead please.

Thanks

Comment: if those are actual CSV files ... please post them _in CSV format_. otherwise those who want to help you have to convert the data to the correct format on their own ... and some of us are too lazy to do that work for you. [*grin*]

Comment: _...throw any lead please."_, you can start from here: [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1), [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1), [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: here is text representation of csv : Name,Number,Priority
John,123,Second
Rocky,345,Third
Tony,234,First
Rocky,345,Second
Matt,999,Second
Bernard,888,Third
Matt,999,First
Jacob,789,Second
Angela,777,Second
Jacob,789,First

Comment: Since your Priority precedence happens to be in alphabetical order, this should make using `Sort-Object` easy for you. You can first `Group-Object` on property `Name`. Then sort each of those groupings on property `Priority`. Then just output the first item in each group.

Comment: Thanks Theo, I tried marking the answer earlier, but it didnt work. I have marked your answer as the correct one, Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. As your examples happen to be all sortable in the wanted order, I have added an extra line to the csv so also a priority 'Fourth' comes into the equasion:

**input.csv**

```
Name,Number,Priority
John,123,Second
Rocky,345,Third
Tony,234,First
Rocky,345,Second
Matt,999,Second
Bernard,888,Third
Matt,999,First
Jacob,789,Second
Angela,777,Second
Jacob,789,First
Angela,777,Fourth
```

Here's three methods you can use:

**Method 1**: create a Hashtable with the priorities and the order number for the sort

```
$prios = @{
    First  = 0
    Second = 1
    Third  = 2
    Fourth = 3
    # etc
}

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv' | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object {$prios[$_.Priority]} | Select-Object -First 1
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Method 2**: create a string array with the priorities in the order you need

```
$prios = 'First','Second','Third','Fourth'  # etc

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv' | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object {$prios.IndexOf($_.Priority)} | Select-Object -First 1
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Method 3**: create an enum with the priorities in the order you need

```
Enum prios {
    First  = 0
    Second = 1
    Third  = 2
    Fourth = 3
    # etc
}

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\input.csv' | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object {[prios]::($_.Priority)} | Select-Object -First 1
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on all cases when displayed on screen:

```
Name    Number Priority
----    ------ --------
John    123    Second  
Rocky   345    Second  
Tony    234    First   
Matt    999    First   
Bernard 888    Third   
Jacob   789    First   
Angela  777    Second
```